# File content to big string

Tags: c, string, file, copy

I want to take all the content of a file **in one go** and put it in a **"big string"**..
I dont want to put line by line. Is there any function to do that?

i want something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *script;
        int i;
        char *code;

        if (argc > 1){
          for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
            if ((script = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL){
            perror(argv[i]);
            }else {
               code = malloc (sizeof(char)*sizeof(script));

               **HERE TAKE THE CONTENT AND PUT IN "CODE" IN ONE GO** 


             }
           }
         }
     printf("%s",code);
     fclose(script);
     free(codigo);
     exit(0);
}
```

Is that posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might also look into using

```
fseek(script, 0, SEEK_END); // position to the end of the file

size = ftell(script); // get the file size

fseek(script, 0, SEEK_SET); // rewind to the beginning of the file

code = malloc(sizeof(char)*(size+1));

if(code) { 
    fread(code, sizeof(char), size, script);
    code[size] = '\0';
}
```

with some additional error checking

Comment: sure... if you man fseek you'll see that it returns 0 on success and -1 otherwise, so something like rc = fseek(...) if(rc) { // handle error }.  Additionally, the fread() should return size bytes, so n = fread(...); if(n!=size) { // handle error }... lastly, you have a free(codigo) in your example... that should probably be something like if(code) free(code)...  In essence, all the functions have a return code or some such that you should always be checking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Read up on `ftell` or `stat` to work on getting the size of the file to find out how much space you need to alloc (you can't use `sizeof` on a `FILE *` to get that info, it won't do what you think), and `fread` to read it in one go.

Sample code to use stat() to get the size:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

off_t fsize(const char *fname) {
    struct stat st;

    if (stat(fname, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;

    return -1; 
}
```